# Drupal CCK field not visible to anonymous users

Tags: drupal, field, visibility, cck

I added a field to a nodetype using CCK, but when I try to view the node as an anonymous user the field is not visible. I can see it when I am logged in with my admin account.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Each CCK field has its own permissions. Each time you add a field you need to go to /admin/user/permissions and make the field viewable for anonymous users if you want people who are not logged in to be able to see that field.[[via]](http://learnbythedrop.com/forum/cck-field-is-just-visible-when-im-logged-in#comment-1340)